# How to save multiple google maps marker, their positions in Firebase Realtime database and show them again when the app is opened

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

I am developing an app where user can click on the map to add a custom marker. Now I want that when the user opens the app again, it shows those custom markers that were added before.

I want to achieve it with the help of Firebase Realtime Database. When the user clicks on the map, that marker location(in the form of lat,lang) should be saved to the database and later should be shown again from the database when the app is opened.

I have no idea how to achieve it. Here is what I have already done:

I created the app and when I am clicking anywhere on the map view, I get the lat, lang and a custom marker is added on the clicked location.

Please be a little bit more informative while answering, it would be a great help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you could use firestore database, Is easier to maintain than real time firebase, IMHO

You could have a collection called points, or a collection per user if this is the case of your app, and each time you receive the marker click  you would call the firestore sdk to add this data like in the [add data section here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?hl=en#add_data), and during your app initialization use the [read data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?hl=en#read_data) to serialize your [geopoints](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint) (the supported data type for geolocation in firebase) and put then in the map as markers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to implement firestore but I'll bother you again maybe if I need help in it

Comment: Good luck dude! - It's pretty straightforward if you follow the docs, tell me if works out

Comment: your suggestion saved my life, thanks a lot buddy. it's working seamlessly

Comment: Glad it help man! if you could mark my answer as correct it would be awesome